# How to catch PHP errors as soft validation

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I using standard `PHP` function:

```
try 
{ 

}
catch (Exception $exc)
  {
        echo   $exc->getMessage();
  }
```

...

```
 throw new Exception('Error Message');
```

to validate data and return various messages to the user. And it works perfectly. But with with this method everything will stops if new Exception been trowed (which is right). But I would like to use soft validation (when error appears but user can process forward). Does `PHP` have something like that?

Comment: The code that throws the Exception must be _inside_ the try block. If that doesn't work, please post more of your code.

Comment: @David yes. This is just an illustration

Comment: It seems to me the solution is already in the title: you `catch` an exception in order for it not to stop everything, to contain the error. You can then decide to continue with your program or not. Please explain better what you're asking.

Comment: If my code have `throw new Exception` then i would like to stop script and show exceptions. but does another method exist to show information like warnings but does not stop execute.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you to understand how the `try...catch` works and how to get the exception messages. Read more about exception here http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Demo code:

```
$exception = [];
try {
   function1();
   function2();
}
catch(Exception $e){
   $exception['msg'] = $e->getMessage();
   $exception['code'] = $e->getCode();
}

function3();
print '<pre>';
print_r($exception);
print '</pre>';
```

Here, the `function3()` will always be executed. But if the function1() throws an exception, `function2()` will not executed further.But If exception occurs you can receive the `$exception` data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to gather the error messages to an array, and return that.

```
if(strlen($username) < 3) $errors[] = "Username is too short";
if(strlen($password) < 3) $errors[] = "Password is too short";

return $errors;
```